.env file not getting pushed to servers
I have built a simple Next.js app for trying to understand kamal better before I use it in production. What I need to do is that I have variables in my code that are taken from the .env file and used in code.
First I created the Next.js app using one of the free templates that they offer. Then initialized kamal and git in this folder. Now the kamal init command created files like in the documentation, one of them being .env. Now inside this .env I put the variables that kamal generated and the variables I use in my code. Then committed the repository and ran kamal setup command. Everything went smoothly and deployment was successful. When I open the page in my web browser where I have used the variable that I added, the value of that isn't retrieved.
I read the documentation and tried to use the kamal env push but it doesn't do anything. Tried to add the env block in the deploy.yml like this:
env:
  secret:
    - VALUE

and ran kamal env push but not working either. Also tried with kamal deploy but no luck either. In the .env file I just have 2 variables KAMAL_REGISTRY_PASSWORD and VALUE. How I use this variable VALUE is simple, as I said I am doing it just for testing purposes, like this:
import React from 'react'

function page() {
  const envVar = process.env.VALUE

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{envVar}</div>
      <div>End of ENV</div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default page


You might be using version 1. Kamal introduced some changes to secrets in version 2. According to Kamal upgrade docs  Secrets moved from .env/.env.rb to .kamal/secrets. Also kamal env push is not a valid command in version 2.

I think Alex's answer might be enough but something else that might be worth mentioning is that by default, kamal will only take into account changes that have been committed.
https://kamal-deploy.org/docs/configuration/builders/#build-context
